# Facebook Login with Cognito User Pools using Amplify's federatedSignIn

Tags: reactjs, facebook, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm trying to get Facebook login working with Cognito User Pools in a React project using `aws-amplify`.

I think I've set up the Facebook App and Cognito User Pool correctly by following various [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-configuring-federation-with-social-idp.html). Note that I'm using User Pools rather than Federated Identities.

I'm a bit stuck and confused on the React side of things. I've tried a few different [guides](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social/q/platform/js#setup-frontend), but all have the same outcome...

The Login button triggers this code:

```
  Auth.configure({
    oauth: {
      domain: 'xxxxxxxxx.auth.eu-west-2.amazoncognito.com',
      redirectSignIn: process.env.REACT_APP_FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_SIGN_IN,
      redirectSignOut: process.env.REACT_APP_FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_SIGN_OUT,
      responseType: 'token'
    },
    region: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_REGION,
    userPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_USER_POOL_ID,
    userPoolWebClientId: process.env.REACT_APP_USER_POOL_WEB_CLIENT_ID
  })
  Auth.federatedSignIn({provider: 'Facebook'})
```

After clicking the Login button, the page is redirected and ends up with this hash in the url:

https://localhost:3000/sign-in#access_token=xxx&state=xxx&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600

If I then call `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()`, I get no user ("The user is not authenticated"), and if I try `Hub.listen("auth")`, the only events that get fired are `parsingCallbackUrl` and `configured` - the page is then redirected and the `signIn` event is never fired.

If I then click on the Login button again (when the url has the hash with `access_token` etc), I will be successfully signed in. If I remove the hash, and try to sign in, it will fail as above.

Any ideas what's going on? Do I need to handle the access token from the hash myself? Why does `Auth.federatedSignIn` only seem to work if the access token is already in the hash?

Answer (score 1):

I've just worked it out... the `Auth.configure` call needed to be moved out of the component and into `App.js`. Everything now seems to be working properly.